# Perl Regular Expression where a word is repeated more than three times non-sequential

Tags: regex, expression, cpu-word

I currently use this to find out my word in logtail

```
**(?=\b\w{5}\b)\b\w*err\w*\b**
```

But I need a regex which will match the expression more than thrice / five times and non-sequential.

Any advice?

Thanks in advance

I do not have any sample data as the ones I have are log files.

2018-07-24 10:03:20,610 DEBUG [Thread-3]: [ERROR] another destroy operation just happened

Then some lines...

then again another [ERROR] message

So my search will look for ERROR and the highlight in Wintail / Notepad++ will highlight the Error & alert me only when the log has crossed 5 error messages or more.

Comment: could you add sample data and expected output to the post?

Comment: Dear Matt, Please read the search word. it contain the word "w*err" word starting with "err" and w{5} means 5 letter word - error.

Comment: Before the post being edited, the regex you had was `(?=\b\w{5}\b)\b\werr\w\b`. this won't match a word starting with `err`. Please edit the post to add sample data against which you are searching.

Comment: Yes, probaly while cut paste, the "*" was removed / probably i made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Since sample data and sample string is not provided, i'll provide a specific example where the string `str` is searched for 3 to 5 occurrences in the the same input string.

```
$String = "str foisdf str wifdoidsfstreoijdsf";

if($String =~ /(str)(.+?\1){2,4}/)
{
    print "Found";
}
```

Here `str`is searched for in $String. the first capture group `(str)` will capture text `str` in \1 and the second group `(.+?\1{2,4})` will match atleast 1 character before matching again with `str`. 


This is repeated for 2 to 4 times. Since `str` is already found once in the regex, the total match will be 3-5 times.


Tried and tested in my PC and is working. In case you need a non-fixed text `str`, try substituting that instead of `str` in the regex.

Comment: Dear Arun, Thanks for your answer but this doesnt work in a one liner search. You mentioned "Since Sample Data & String are not provided", my search itself contains the word - its "error" and "w{5}" means 5 letter word. It highlights only once. I need it match 5 times.